# Django: reference relationship in fixture using unique key(s)

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have the following database models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)


class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm creating a fixture to load initial data into these tables, which looks like this:

```
# TEAMS
- model: load.team
  fields:
    id: 1
    name: Raiders

# PLAYERS
- model: load.player
  fields:
    team: 1
    name: Derek Carr
- model: load.player
  fields:
    team: 1
    name: Darren Waller
```

This works fine, but I'd like to reference team by its unique column `name` (for a more human readable file), so the player fixtures would look like this:

```
# PLAYERS
- model: load.player
  fields:
    team: Raiders
    name: Derek Carr
- model: load.player
  fields:
    team: Raiders
    name: Darren Waller
```

Is there anyway to do this, besides setting `Team.name` as the primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [Natural keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/#natural-keys) for this.

You should create a custom manager for `Team` and implement the `get_by_natural_key` function. You should also define a natural_key function on the Team object:

```
class TeamManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get(name=name)

class Team(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = TeamManager()

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.name,)
```

Then you can use `dumpdata --natural-foreign` to create fixtures using the Player's natural key.